# Placing the \a on the output stream does not produce a sound

Tags: c++, c

This was prompted by some experimenting with C/C++; neither the statement

```
printf("\a");
```

nor the statement

```
cout << "\a";
```

produce an audible bell sound. How is the \a supposed to function . . .

Comment: Computers don't have bells anymore.  Turn on your speakers.

Comment: this is trick from previous century :)

Comment: @Andrey, I believe it could go back to the century before that...

Comment: I started to feel very melancholic... aaaaaaah good old times

Answer (score 9):

Although the ASCII BEL control character has a well-defined meaning, its exact interpretation in your console is highly platform dependent. C defines `\a` as the escape sequence for the ASCII BEL character found at code 7 and sometimes known as Ctrl+G. In the good old days, this control code allowed the bell of a remote terminal to be rung to alert the remote operator that a message needed attention.

In modern systems, the bell has largely been replaced by other mechanisms. You console window (whether an xterm or similar on *nix or a Console Windows on Windows) now has the responsibility of doing something "sensible" with that control character. It also has the freedom to ignore it completely.

On Windows, you can achieve an audible alert by calling [`MessageBeep()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680356%28VS.85%29.aspx), passing `0xffffffff` to get a simple beep noise that uses no system resources, `MB_OK` or another `MB_ICON*` constant to get one of the system event sounds.

Answer (score 2):

Be thankful.  I guess you have not been misfortunate enough to have tried displaying the listing of a binary file in a busy office.

Answer (score 0):

You may have access to the **aplay** utility (GNU/Linux, etc.):

```
#include <cstdlib>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    system("yes \"ZaaZa\" | aplay -c 2"); // stop this with ctrl-c
}
```

You can send whatever raw sound (or with some encodings, see the `-f` option) to aplay. Type `man aplay` for its manual.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at the configuration of your console.  I don't know how Windows handles it, but on Linux, the console can be configured to ignore the system bell, or play a custom sound in its place.  I'd try looking at the console's configuration as a first step before moving on to more complex solutions like aplay.

Answer (score 0):

The terminal software assigned to `STDOUT` decides what to do with the `\a` character. You may try using another terminal software. Or dig deep into the settings of your terminal. Maybe there is a switch to enable/disable the bell sound.